# Photo Competition 2021-06-21: Long Exposure

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Long Exposure

Either a picture containing motion blur (star trails, cars on a road etc.) or a combination of several photos to create a time-lapse in one photo.

This theme was suggested by [damned truths](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125104/photo-competition-2021-06-07-long-exposure?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on June 21, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the late contest, I was traveling all weekend, and forgot about the contest schedule.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Pay Here

People's Park, Saint Helier, Bailiwick of Jersey

6 August 2016

Nikon D750, Nikkor 50mm f1.2, 3 seconds (tripod), ISO 140.

Walking around the park taking some ordinary long exposure photos and filling the frame with motion blur, I noticed the ticket taker in the booth sitting perfectly still and thought "could be an interesting photo", so I backed up a little to include the ticket booth.

[image: Night time long exposure of carnival ride]

Comment: Nice one. The ticket booth makes it 10 times more interesting, it's the key element for me.

Comment: Did you merge two separate photos to get the booth in focus, or is there some camera trick to do that?

Comment: It's a single photo taken with an old lens. I have several "Non-CPU" lenses and the Exif aperture value recorded is not reliable. (I assume you are asking about shallow DOF at f/1.2, right?) It's entirely possible the aperture was smaller but I typically use this lens wide open at night.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

## Plodda Falls

Location: Plodda Falls, Scotland

Date: 2018-08-28

Camera: Panasonic DC-GX1, 14-42@14mm, f/4.5, 0.5 sec, iso 150

Answer (score 21):

[image]

## Gave de Lutour

- Location: Pyrénées, France.
- Date: June 14<sup>th</sup>, 2018.
- Camera: Nikon D7000; Nikkor 70–200mm lens; tripod.
- Settings: ƒ/11.0, 70.0 mm, 13 s., ISO 100.

Answer (score 17):

Cherry Grove Sunset. Taken at Cherry Grove Beach, SC, in October, 2012  with a Sony Alpha 65 and a neutral density filter. The original photo was taken at f/32 and ISO-100 with a 15 second exposure to smooth out the waves. I split the ARW file into 3 bracketed exposures and combined them using tone mapping to get this final image. Note that while the camera was on a tripod, there was a bit of wind blowing that may have affected the sharpness of the pier in the image. But the people on the pier were relatively still the whole time.[image]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Johny Mnemonic's dream]

***Johny Mnemonic's dream***

*Location: Warsaw, Poland
*Date: 24-12-2020
*Camera: Nikon D750, Nikkor 20mm 2.8 AIS lens, f/22, 2 sec, ISO 100

Answer (score 13):

[image: traffic signs]

### Bumpy Road

Location: Autobahn A8, Mühlhausen, Germany

Date: 2018-12-26

Camera: Nikon D3100, 55-300@300mm, f18, 6s, 80km/h, ISO 450

Comment: Autobahn bumpy??

Comment: @Zeus: Our Autobahns are smooth like a baby bottom, always.

Answer (score 13):

### Bay Bridge in the Fog

San Francisco, June 27th 2020

Canon 500D, Tamron 70-300

f/25, 5 seconds, ISO100

[image]

Answer (score 11):

### Hours on the Highway

Taken in the car, took a lot of shots to get the blur perfect.

California, February 14th 2021

Canon 500D, Tamron 70-300

f/16, 1/10, ISO100

[image]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Milky Way Rising]

Location: Mauna Kea Observatory, Hilo, Hawaii.
Date: October 11th 2017.
Camera Sony A7, 18mm, f2.8 ISO 6400, 15sec exposure

Answer (score 10):

## Ice Cave

[image: ice cave]

Location: Eisriesenwelt, Austria

Date: 2019-08-16

Camera: Nikon D3100, 18-55@18mm, f5, 4s, ISO 3200

The entrance is at the bottom of the cave, these people are actually on the way out.

Answer (score 10):

### Downtown Bangkok accident

Location: Silom road in Bangkok. Settings: f/4, 1/2 second exposure, 64.84mm (image is cropped) at ISO500 with a Sony RX10M3. Photo was taken in March of 2021.

[image]

Comment: Damn, I wish you'd have gone for higher exposure time. A bit more blur would take it to a whole new level.

Comment: @MaxD Yea, I took like a hundred but I think they're all short like this. I was playing around with the composition and I don't think I fully locked it into the tripod (just using it for support). I'll try to post a longer exposure of the same intersection but without the accident. :)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Long exposure entry]
Exposure settings unknown. Taken using an Olympus Pen-F, 17mm Zuiko f/1.8 in Gelderland, The Netherlands

Answer (score 7):

### Carousel ride at night

May the 25th in 2019, time of day 21:48, Strasbourg, France.
[image: carousel ride at night]

Camera was placed on something available at the location, no tripod was available/used.

Leica Q2

- ISO 64,
- 28mm
- f/10.0
- 1 sec

Answer (score 6):

## Winter Bridge

Bobrava stream, near Brno, Czechia, 2021-02-13

Nikon D810, Nikon AF-S 24-70mm f/2.8G ED @ 32 mm, 4", F/22, ISO 64, Polarizing filter

[image: Winter Bridge]

Answer (score 5):

### Bangkok intersection traffic patterns

Location: Silom road in Bangkok, Thailand. Settings: f/4, 3.2 second exposure, 54.57mm (image is cropped) at ISO160 with a Sony RX10M3. Photo was taken in March of 2021.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Shinjuku Station Traffic

From the bridge of one of the exits of Shinjuku Station.
Tokyo, October 2008

[image: Shijuku Station traffic]

Canon EOS Kiss X2, EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II (cropped)

f/16, 2.0 s, ISO 400

Answer (score 4):

### Diwali

November 14 2020, Los Gatos, CA

Canon 500D

f/9, 1/60, ISO3200

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Huh?

Welwyn Garden City, June 2021

- Camera: Zenza Bronica ETRSi
- Film: Agfapan APX100 (expired in 2001 so shot at 80 ISO and pushed a bit)
- Lense: Zenzanon PE 75mm
- Settings: f2.8 (most likely) at either 1/2s or 1s shutter speed.

[image: blurry cat]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

## Fireworks in Germany

Location: Düsseldorf, Germany

Date: 2015-12-31

Camera: Panasonic DC-GX1, 14-42@14mm, f/9, 20 sec, iso 160

Answer (score 4):

### Boat messing up the reflections

May 23rd 2019, time of day 20:38, Strasbourg, France.
[image: boat messing up the reflections]

Leica Q2

- no tripod was used, camera was placed on a bridge railing
- 28mm
- f/16.0
- ISO 200
- 5 sec

Answer (score 4):

"Kitchen Inferno", a kitchen in Germany, Sony DSC-R1, 2020-01-01, ISO160, f=14.3mm varied to 71.5mm (24mm to 120mm equivalent to 135 format) during 7sec exposure, postprocessing in RawTherapee.
[image: Kitchen Inferno]

Answer (score 3):

### Busy Bangkok intersection

The intersection of Rama I and Phayathai road in Bangkok (a.k.a. the Pathumwan intersection) as seen from the walkway in the north east corner. There are some light trails on the opposite side of the road (note that the emergency responders are parked there). Unfortunately, I couldn't get steady longer exposures because of the tripod police guarding the walkways.

Settings: f/2.4, 0.5 second exposure, 8.8mm at ISO125 with a Sony RX10M3. Photo was taken in April of 2021.

[image]